# C++: shared_ptr in vector is not updating the original shared_ptr

Tags: c++, vector, tree, shared-ptr

I'm doing a school homework with c++ (i'm still learning). i'm trying to implement randomly generated binary tree structures, using shared_ptr to store information of a Node on multiple places(i need that for the homework). Consider the following sample code(this is my little test program):

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


struct Node : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Node> {
    char charValue;
    int intValue;
    std::shared_ptr<Node > left;
    std::shared_ptr<Node > right;
    std::shared_ptr<Node > parent;

    std::shared_ptr<Node> getPtr()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }

    Node() : intValue(0)
    {
        charValue = 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> treeQueue;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> root = std::make_shared<Node>();

    treeQueue.clear();
    treeQueue.push_back(root->left);  //std::shared_ptr<Node>(root->left)); //root->left->getPtr()); 
    treeQueue.push_back(root->right);  //std::shared_ptr<Node>(root->right)); //root->right->getPtr());

    treeQueue[1] = std::make_shared<Node>(); //std::shared_ptr<Node>(new Node);
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, i intialize a root,and i want to keep every other node of a tree empty until i choose it in the tree structure. And in my homework, i decide which Node i'm gonna choose after i push it in the vector treeQueue. (I randomly pick it from there).

**THE PROBLEM:** For example, in the code above, when i initialize treeQueue[1], i expect root->right to be also initialized. Because they're the same pointers. But it stays empty! I also put the alternative ways I've tried to push it in treeQueue (which also didn't work). I've tried "enable_shared_from_this" too,which is why it's there.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there another technique that will provide the same functionality that i need?

I learned that it's not healthy to use raw pointers so i used shared_ptr which makes sense, but now i get this problem. Please help me, i'm gonna lose my mind. I searched everywhere i could. I tried everything i found.

Comment: Why are you expecting `root->right` to be initialized? You're not initializing it anywhere.

Comment: `treeQueue[1] = std::make_shared<Node>()` doesn't affect `root->right`, you just erase an empty `shared_ptr` (copy of `root->right`) by a new value. You might want `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>*>`...

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Aren't treQueue[1] and root->right the same pointers? So when i initialize one, i thought the other would also point to the same object. Or at least that's what i intended to do.

Comment: I want to push the shared_ptr into the vector when its empty, an when i randomly pick it from the vector to initialize ,i want the original shared_ptr (root->right) to also be initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sam Varshavchik for making me understand my mistake. And i ended up also taking Jarod42's suggestion and used treeQueue as

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>*>
```

and it worked. So i'm marking this comment as the solution, as a reference to those two comments :)

Answer (score 6):

`shared_ptr` shares what the `ptr` is pointing to. The `shared_ptr` itself is not "shared" in any way, shape, matter, or form. Each `shared_ptr` that references the same object (that's being shared), is its own, separate, discrete shared pointer.

Here, you copied one `shared_ptr` to another `shared_ptr`. Then you replaced the copy of a `shared_ptr` with another, newly-constructed, `shared_ptr`.

That newly-constructed `shared_ptr` has nothing to do with the original `shared_ptr` that the first one, the one that was copied from, is referencing.

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
int *a=NULL;

int *b=a;

b=new int{4};
```

Do you expect, now, `*a` to return `4`?. Of course not. They are two completely different pointers.

Comment: Ohhh, i understand, thanks. Can you suggest any way to accomplish this then?

Comment: You should initialize left/right in `Node()`'s constructor. But then you'll have another issue: if you create a tree linked entirely by `shared_ptr`s (whether it's done properly in the constructor, or manually), you will create a circular reference (between parent and children), which will result in memory leaks. Now that you've learned all about `shared_ptr`, you will also then need to learn what weak pointers are all about.